# Subqueries on main table cancel each other out?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First post.

I have a table where I want to count the rows where a certain value appears. In total I want two count() rows that are dependent on different value in another column (Y and N). I thought it best to do with two joins on the table itself. However, the result is no rows at all. id is unique (Primary Key).

**What am I missing?** Its like they cancel each other out because if I only run with one join and respective count() it works. Or if there is a better way to solve this. Thanks!

```
 select
 a.loans,
 count(b.loans) as count_new_cust,
 count(c.loans) as count_old_cust
 FROM  applications a 
,(SELECT distinct id, loans FROM  applications where new_cust='Y') b 
,(SELECT distinct id, loans FROM  applications where new_cust='N') c
  where a.id=b.id  and b.id=c.id
  group by a.loans
  order by a.loans DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to `JOIN`. You can use *conditional aggregation* instead:

```
select a.loans,
       count(case when new_cust='Y' then a.loans END) as count_new_cust,
       count(case when new_cust='N' then a.loans END) as count_old_cust
FROM  applications a 
group by a.loans
order by a.loans DESC
```

Comment: Damn it. Perfect example of over thinking it. Thanks! Your solution did it!

Comment: Follow up question. Do you, or anyone, have any wise tips when to use a subquery in SELECT or FROM and when not to (like the answer you provided)?

Comment: @CobraKaj The query that uses the least table access operations is always preferable. In this case my query access table `applications` just one, whereas you query access the same table three times.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was thinking more in the technical line. When you're after X do Y kinda way. When is your solution not good and a subquery with itself better? Thanks for the answers btw